# I need to move nodes real fast, to a location

Tags: ios, swift

I created this code to move nodes in my scene real fast. I created a function that spawns a node named ball, but have 2 different textures on it. So I spawn with a function two different nodes. Now I have to move every node individually. Even when there are 10 balls on the screen. Is this possible? I found a code, but when I move my finger too fast, it stops the movement. The code that I pasted, doesn't even work at all.

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {        
    for touch in touches {
        location = touch.location(in: self)

        if ball.name == "ballblauw" {
            if location == ball.position {
                let ballX = ball.position.x
                let ballY = ball.position.y

                ballLocation = CGPoint(x: ballX, y: ballY)
            }
        }

        if ball.name == "ballrood" {
            if location == ball.position {
                let ballX = ball.position.x
                let ballY = ball.position.y

                ballLocation = CGPoint(x: ballX, y: ballY)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        location = touch.location(in: self)

        if ball.name == "ballblauw" {
            ballLocation = location
        }

        if ball.name == "ballrood" {
            ballLocation = location
        }
    }
}
```